# 2 разных домена с одинаковым контентом

Tags: apache, nginx, debian, php-fpm

Доброго времени суток.

Есть корневая папка с главным сайтом:

```
/var/www/user/data/www/site.ru
```

Следовательно обращаемся мы к сайту через site.ru.

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при обращении к другому домену, пример site.com, контент брался с той же корневой папки главного сайта site.ru. Я не хочу редирект, а именно полное зеркало.

site.com я уже припарковал к серверу. Оба домена находятся на одном IP. Новый домен уже откликается.

Сама задача, как реализовать это на Debian в связке Nginx+Apache+PHP-FPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конфиге апача прописать [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias)

`<VirtualHost *> VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru
ServerName site.ru
ServerAlias site.com
..`

Если установлена панель - делать алиасы (псевдонимы) через неё.

> site.com я уже припарковал к серверу. Оба домена находятся на одном IP. Новый домен уже откликается.

Если "припарковал " = создал ещё один www-домен  (виртуалхост), то удалить его.